# Gtk how to bring my app to foregrout when it is minimized or in another workspace

Tags: python, gtk, gtk3, pygtk, pygobject

I am trying to develop a simple Gtk app which should be launched with a custom shortcut.
Right now, I call the following methods to present the window to the user:

```py
# if the user executes the same shortcut but another instance is already opened, we skip this part
 if not self.window:
            # when the last one is closed the application shuts down
            self.window = MyCustomClass()

self.window.show_all()
self.window.present()
```

however, if the app is minimized in another workspace it is maximized but doesn't get the focus.

Do you know how I can fix this?

EDIT ✅:

I ended up using [Wnck](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Wnck-3.0), which if you are building a flatpak is not included by default in the runtime: you can compile it from source [like this](https://flatpak-modules.vercel.app/).

Then, I use the name of my app + the name of the icon (just to be sure) to move my app around.

https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Wnck-3.0/classes/Window.html#Wnck.Window.move_to_workspace

Comment: Have you tried adding `self.window.grab_focus()`? That should work.

Comment: That didn't work. The window does in fact grab the focus, but in another workspace 